# Is it possible to manually trigger the micro deposit initiation after connecting a bank account in the auth flow?

Tags: plaid

I work for a fintech broker-dealer company that uses react and graphql on the front end, and spring boot on the backend. We allow clients to link their bank accounts via the Plaid integration modal. We want to move this "link bank account" step earlier in our flow, when clients are still drafting their brokerage accounts, before the associated brokerage account is open. We want to prompt users to enter their bank account details in the plaid modal, save the returned data (public token, institution data, plaid metadata) to a draft table, and only initiate the link process when the associated brokerage account is opened. This could be minutes or months after they go through the plaid modal in our draft flow. For micro deposit strategies, we want to delay the micro deposits actually hitting their bank accounts until the brokerage account is opened. But the way I understand it, plaid automatically initiates the micro deposit flow from their modal. Is there a way I can delay that micro deposit process, so that I can manually trigger it once the associated brokerage account is opened?

From reading documentation, it seems like this is an automated process and can't be triggered manually. But I could be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. It is not possible for a user to link an account via Plaid that hasn't yet been opened. Aside from the inability to delay the micro-deposit, authorization options such as OAuth flows do not support granting consent if the user does not already have an account at the institution at the time when the Link flow takes place. Also note that the public token has a lifetime of 30 minutes, so it cannot be persisted for months.